# Android Studio: ArrayAdapter issues with listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use a custom layout for a listview, as well as a string array pulled from res/strings. At first I tried using

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.android_versions,R.layout.list_view_custom)
```

But got an error message you must supply a resource ID for a textview, upon which the emulator would shut down. So I tried using newArrayAdapter as seen in the code below, using the 4th line to obtain my string array. Since this all worked before I tried using a custom layout, I think the issue lies somewhere in the 4th, 9th, and 10th lines.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    List<String> android_versions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.android_versions));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_view_custom,R.id.listview_custom,android_versions);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is the layout of the ListViewActivity, content_list_view., which is obtained through activity_list_view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.andrewtakao.testapp.ListViewActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_list_view">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the layout I am trying to implement into the ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listview_custom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/apple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally here is my newest error message:

> -18 18:51:17.682 12567-12567/com.example.andrewtakao.testapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread. 10-18 18:55:11.808
>   12567-12567/com.example.andrewtakao.testapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM 10-18 18:55:11.809 12567-12567/com.example.andrewtakao.testapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.andrewtakao.testapp, PID: 12567
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.andrewtakao.testapp/com.example.andrewtakao.testapp.ListViewActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:551)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.andrewtakao.testapp.ListViewActivity.(ListViewActivity.java:20)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                        at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong?? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception details that you're passing a null context to and I suspect it's here:

```
List<String> android_versions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.android_versions));
```

Move your list instantiation inside the `onCreate`.

```
List<String> android_versions;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    android_versions = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.android_versions))
    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

**Explanation:** Using `getResources()` in the `Activity` implicitly refers to the `Activity` itself which is a `Context` in its own accord. Since before `onCreate` being called the `Context` is not yet instantiated the `Context` will be null. Only after the `onCreate` is called the `Context` is available.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. but could you also e

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much- could you also explain where the null context is being passed?

Comment: @AndrewTakao There is the explanation for you. ;)